# Бесконечный ввод а потом вывод

Tags: c++, строки, ввод, вектор

мне нужно что бы я мог бесконечно вводить текст а при вводе "end" все что я ввел вывелось, через обычный массив на указанное кол-во элементов я задачку сделал, но не могу сделать через динамический массив или вектор, как не попробую не получается. Буду очень благодарен за помощь

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


int main() {
setlocale(0, "ru");
string n = "";
int s = 0;
int i = 0;
vector<string> password[1];
while (n != "end") {
    cin >> n;
    s++;
    password->resize[s];
    for (; i < s; i++) {
        password[i].push_back(n);
    }
}
for (int g = 0; g < password->size(); g++) {
    cout << password << " ";
}

}
```

Моя неудачная попытка сделать это через вектор (Желательно через динамический массив)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так сойдет?

```
int main()
{
    string n = "";
    vector<string> password;

    while (cin >> n && n != "end")
        password.push_back(n);

    for (auto g : password)
    {
        cout << g << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное, а можно это как-то реализовать только через динамический массив?

Comment: Если именно динамический массив - то это оно и есть: динамический, т.е. изменяющий размер. Если "через массив в динамической памяти" - то это будет либо выделенный заранее массив достаточно большого размера, чтобы гарантированно поместить весь ввод, либо нужно писать свою упрощенную реализацию вектора...

Comment: Спасибо огромное, побольше бы таких людей)